# StreamWriter Writes everything on same line

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a small HttpWebRequest that grabs some text from a online .txt file

After it gets it i want to save it to a .txt file on the computer.

Content of the text is formatet like this:

```
Line one
Line two
Line four
Line Five
Line ten etc.
```

But when it saves it ends up like this:

```
Line oneLine twoLine fourLine FiveLine ten etc.
```

How may I fix this?

Code is as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest WebReq3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://test.net/test.txt");

HttpWebResponse WebResp3 = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq3.GetResponse();

System.IO.StreamReader sr3 = new System.IO.StreamReader(WebResp3.GetResponseStream());


System.IO.StreamWriter _WriteResult = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\Test.txt");
_WriteResult.Write(sr3.ReadToEnd());
_WriteResult.Close();

sr3.Close();
```

Comment: Are you reading both txt files using the same editor? Sometimes different editors interpret newline differently

Comment: @SystemDown, yes; stated another way. This has got to be an encoding issue.

Comment: Are you really sure that the text content your receive has line feeds? Check in the debugger by reading the byte data **directly from the response stream** into a sufficiently large byte array and search inside that byte array for line feed characters (decimal 10, 13)

Comment: @Merceyz: What shows up correctly in Notepad++? The text file your code received/wrote? Or just the original text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read data using `ReadLine()` and write using `WriteLine()` instead of `ReadToEnd()` and `WriteToEnd()`.

Remove this line:

```
_WriteResult.Write(sr3.ReadToEnd());
```

And modify your code with this:

```
string readval = sr3.ReadLine();
while(readval != null)
{
    _WriteResult.WriteLine(readval);
    readval = sr3.ReadLine();
}
```

For more details, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hello Downvoter, user has already accepted this as answer. Can you explain why you have downvoted ?

Comment: @kumarch1 while it wasn't me, I noticed your answer wasn't very well formatted. Fixed that now. (most obvious problem was link you posted as code for some odd reason)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard oh..ok. Thanks. it's fine. you have modified the link. That's what required. Instead of downvote, it's better to edit the answer(mostly the answers which are already accepted).Such that it will help me as well as to the user who asked the question. Thanks

Comment: @kumarch1 of course, but maybe someone thought the code itself is not good, maybe it's just a downvote troll... we can't know and shouldn't be too upset over this. :)